# Do the compounds NaₓIrO₂ and NaOsO₂ exist?

Tags: physical-chemistry, synthesis, materials, transition-metals, reference-request

Based on some physics background, I want to know whether have scientists synthesized these two materials: $\ce{Na_{$x$}IrO2}$ and $\ce{NaOsO2}$ in the lab, if so, what properties do they have?

I will be very appreciative if someone could recommend me some relevant articles.

> Would you be willing to share your interest in these two materials? For example, is there a specific application in mind? If so, we might be able to suggest alternate materials should these two not exist.

I want to seek a material that has triangular lattice structure, strong spin-orbital coupling (e.g. 5d element) and large (or moderate) coulomb interaction between electrons. For example, $\ce{ABO2}$ type, $\ce{NaOsO2}$ compounds, where $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{B}$ are alkali and transition-metal ions, respectively. So far, I know $\ce{IrTe2}$ may be a one. 
Do you mean that both $\ce{NaxIrO2}$ and $\ce{NaOsO2}$ do not exist?

> Is there any information on iridium and osmium oxides in these low oxidation states?

For example, $\ce{Na2IrO3}$ and $\ce{Li2IrO3}$. But these two belong to the honeycomb lattice structure, and what about the triangular lattice structure?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. Would you be willing to share your interest in these two materials? For example, is there a specific application in mind? If so, we might be able to suggest alternate materials should these two not exist.

Comment: Is there any information on iridium and osmium oxides in these low oxidation states?

Comment: @Ben Norris I want to seek a material that has triangular lattice structure, strong spin-orbital coupling (e.g. 5d element) and large(or moderate) coulomb interaction between electrons. For example, ABO$_2$ type(NaOsO$_2$) compounds, where A and B are alkali and transition-metal ions, respectively. So far, I know IrTe$_2$ may be a one. Do you mean that both Na$_x$IrO$_2$ and NaOsO$_2$ do not exist?Thank you very much.

Comment: @Klaus Warzecha For example, Na$_2$IrO$_3$ and Li$_2$IrO$_3$. But these two belong to the honeycomb lattice structure, and what about the triangular lattice structure? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't know about those two compounds but 1. Potassium osmate is well known and researched. I couldn't find any corresponding sodium salt. 2. $\ce{Na2IrO3}$ is well known. [In 2017, a corresponding copper salt was synthesized](http://ciqm.harvard.edu/uploads/2/3/3/4/23349210/abramchuk2017.pdf) from it. Also, a  new sodium iridate of formula [$\ce{NaIrO3}$ is discovered and synthesized from the former compound](https://pubs.rsc.org/-/content/getauthorversionpdf/C5DT03188E).

Comment: ...and in a [2019 paper](https://scinapse.io/papers/2963774277): "although neither experimental nor theoretical investigation on homologous derivatives NaIrO2 is available in the literature. However, the photocatalytic properties are not explored up to date"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\ce{Na_{x}IrO2}$ the current answer seems to be "no" it has not been made but it is discussed in the literature theoretically.

From [Kitaev-Heisenberg models for iridates on the triangular, hyperkagome, kagome, fcc, and pyrochlore lattices](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.3290):

> However, no triangular lattice iridate with the relevant edge sharing octahedra structure is currently available; a compound of the
>   type NaxIrO2 may or may not turn out to be stabilized.

and in [Chiral spin liquid and topological superconductivity in the undoped and doped
triangular Kitaev-Heisenberg model](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.7820.pdf):

> In addition, a class of ABO2 (where A and B are alkali and transition metal ions, respectively) type transition metal compounds and the possible material NaxIrO2 may be potential candidates for realizing the triangular Kitaev-Heisenberg model.

(But that's your paper isn't it? I don't have any information beyond what you already know, so really this is a useless answer.)